# Repeating a part of an equation

Tags: equations

In tikz, it is possible to define some formatting and apply it in several parts of the tikz drawing; such as using:

```
\tikzset{boxs/.style={draw, very thick, black, rounded corners=5pt}}
```

I use a part of equations repeatedly, as (x_i - \bar{x}) in my example.

Is there a way to define something, as a macro or a style, for this part and apply it in other locations as it is possible in tikz.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{equation*}
\beta = \frac{\displaystyle ‎‎\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x}) (y_i - \bar{y})} {\displaystyle ‎‎\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
\end{equation*}
\vspace {.2cm}
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle ‎‎\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2 = \displaystyle ‎‎\sum_{i=1}^{n} (2 - 2)^2 = 0
\end{equation*}
\vspace {.2cm}
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle ‎‎\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})\bar{x} = \bar{x}\displaystyle ‎‎\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x}) = 0
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to store the repeating elements in a macro:

```
\newcommand{\RepeatingFormula}{(x_i - \bar{x})}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\newcounter{repform}
\newcommand{\RepeatingFormula}{(x_i - \bar{x})}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{equation*}
\beta = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula (y_i - \bar{y})}{%
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula^2}
\end{equation*}
\vspace {.2cm}
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula^2 = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} (2 - 2)^2 = 0
\end{equation*}
\vspace {.2cm}
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula\bar{x} = \bar{x}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula = 0
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to add a frame, you could e.g. use `tikz` and `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{repform}
\newcommand{\RepeatingFormula}{\stepcounter{repform}%
\tikzmarknode[draw=red,rounded corners=1pt]{repform-\number\value{repform}}{(x_i - \bar{x})}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{equation*}
\beta = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula (y_i - \bar{y})}{%
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula^2}
\end{equation*}
\vspace {.2cm}
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula^2 = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} (2 - 2)^2 = 0
\end{equation*}
\vspace {.2cm}
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula\bar{x} = \bar{x}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula = 0
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a bonus, you can use these nodes for all sort of things.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{repform}
\newcommand{\RepeatingFormula}{\stepcounter{repform}%
\tikzmarknode[draw=red,rounded corners=1pt,inner ysep=2pt]{repform-\number\value{repform}}{(x_i - \bar{x})}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{equation*}
\beta = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula (y_i - \bar{y})}{%
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula^2}
\end{equation*}
\vspace {.2cm}
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula^2 = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} (2 - 2)^2 = 0
\end{equation*}
\vspace {.2cm}
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula\bar{x} = \bar{x}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \RepeatingFormula = 0
\end{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[red,stealth-stealth](repform-2) to[out=-90,in=90] (repform-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, for security reasons, I can not install tikzmark or any other package on my work computer. Is there a way to define a macro or a style inside my tex document to use it. p.s. I do not care about the red frame. I used it only for clarifying reason. I just need to repeat the part of the formula.

Comment: @Hany You can store the repeating part in a macro. I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is just what I need.